# Average sum of distances of Poisson point process falling in Poisson-Voronoi cells

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-process, point-processes

## Exercise

Having two homogeneous and independent Poisson point processes $\Phi_3, \Phi_2$ defined in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with intensities $\lambda_3, \lambda_2$, respectively. Having a Voronoi tessellation with cells centered in the points generated by $\Phi_3$, and defining $V_x(\Phi_3)$ as a Voronoi cell centered in $x\in \Phi_3$. Show that:

$$ \mathbb{E}_{\Phi_3}^o \sum_{z \in \Phi_2 \cap V_o(\Phi_3)} \|z\| = \frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_3} \mathbb{E}_{\Phi_2}^o \|z_o\| \tag 1 $$

where $z_o$ is the point of the point process $\Phi_2$ nearest to the origin $o$, and $\mathbb{E}_{\Phi_3}^o$ denotes the Palm expectation respect point process $\Phi_3$.

## What I've tried

First of all I've expressed the LHS of (1) as $\mathbb{E}_{\Phi_3}^o \sum_{z \in \Phi_2} \|z\| \cdot _{V_o(\Phi_3)}(z) $. The I reformulate that as $\mathbb{E}_{\Phi_3}^o \sum_{z \in \Phi_2}f(z)$ and use [Neveu's exchange formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnFCh.jpg) to get:

$$ \frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_3} \mathbb{E}_{\Phi_2}^o \sum_{t \in \Phi_3} f(-t) = \frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_3} \mathbb{E}_{\Phi_2}^o \sum_{t \in \Phi_3} \|t\| \cdot _{V_o(\Phi_3)}(-t)  \tag 2  $$

Since the Voronoi cell $V_o(\Phi_3)$ only has one point $t \in \Phi_3$ in it, and that is precisely $o$, (2) turns out to be:

$$\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_3} \mathbb{E}_{\Phi_2}^o  \|o\| $$

but clearly $\|o\|$ is not the same as $z_o$. I think I'm not using correctly Neveu's exchange formula, which I studied at the "Stochastic and Integral Geometry" book of Schneider and Weil (Theorem 3.4.5).

#### Note

I'm trying to understand the demonstration of the cost formula of the article "[Are Heterogeneous Cloud-Based Radio Access Networks Cost Effective?](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7110548/)".